# Wordpress Contact form 7 not showing form but only shortcode

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

I've activated the plugin Contact Form 7. I've copy and added the shortcode to my page. When trying to view the form it just shows the shortcode. I've tried to add it in text mode. I've added a filter to try to get the form to show.

```
function shortcodes_in_cf7( $form ) {
$form = do_shortcode( $form );
return $form;
}
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'shortcodes_in_cf7' );
```

It doesn't matter what I try it's still showing the shortcode.
I uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin.
I have a custom theme and when I activate a default theme it works fine, but on my theme it shows the shortcode. I'm new to wordpress. My theme without the shortcode works like it should. Is there something else that I'm missing to add cf7 to my custom theme?

Here's the code for displaying the contact page.

```
<?php get_header();

 while(have_posts()) {
   the_post()


?>
<h2 class="page-heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<div id="post-container">
<section id="blogpost">
    <div class="card">
        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {?>
        <div class="card-image">
            <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID())?>" alt="Card Image">
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="card-description">
            <?php echo get_the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
<?php } ?>
<aside id="sidebar">
    <h3>Sidebar Heading</h3>
    <p>Sidebar 1</p>
</aside>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: you need to do do_shortcode on the content of your page if you are not using the_content or get_content. Show us the template used to display this page

Comment: I added it in code section above.

Comment: Thanks Alex, you guided me in the right direction. I was using get_the_content, when I used just the_content it showed on my page. Thanks again.